# Prestashop how to show module below banner?

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop-1.6, banner

How to display Prestashop module below banner. I am using Prestashop 1.6.18

**Section to insert module**

[image: Section to insert module]

**Module is displayed at the end of homepage**

[image: Module displays at the end of homepage]

Answer (score 0):

Try attach your module to another hook. 
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Front+office+Positions

Comment: I tired this. When using live edit drag and drop it shows red colour and i cant drag it there. I am stuck on this since weeks